# Javascript / Json / Firestore code to firestore bulk upload

Tags: javascript, json, google-cloud-firestore

We are looking for ways to bulk upload data into google firestore and found here in Stack Overflow an awesome script to do so, sort of. The problem is that when data is uploaded the collection is fine,  document is fine, but nesting some data we can only manage to import as "map" type when we need "array" and "map". Since we are basically newbies trial and error has not been enough. We appreciate if you can take a look at the code and help us with that.

So far, with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>


    <script>
        var config = {
            apiKey: 'MY API KEY',
            authDomain: 'MY AUTHDOMAIN',
            projectId: 'MY PROJECT ID'
        };
        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        var firestore = firebase.firestore();

        //Paste from the CSV to JSON converter
        const data = [
            {
                "collection": "sub_cats",
                "uid": "Av9vJ0EoFfxhAR2",
                "class": "especialidades_medicas",
                "id": 0,
                "name": "Cardiologo",
                "ind": "11",
                "district": ""
            },
            {
                "collection": "sub_cats",
                "uid": "Av9vJ0EoFfxhAR2",
                "class": "especialidades_medicas",
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Urologo",
                "ind": "12",
                "district": ""
            }
        ]

        var promises = [];

        data.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
        var docRef = firestore.collection(arrayItem.collection).doc(arrayItem.uid);
        var objClass = {};
        var objId = {};
        objId[arrayItem.id] = { name: arrayItem.name, ind: arrayItem.ind };
        objClass[arrayItem.class] = objId;

        promises.push(docRef.set(objClass, { merge: true }));
    });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

we get this:

[data structure current / needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFFu7.jpg)

How would you modify this code to get the array / map structure?

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [arrayUnion()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#static-arrayunion) of fieldValue that can be used with set() or update(). So basically if you use it with update it will "merge" the new value with the existing array values in your document. Inside that you can have your map or any datatype you want.

An example code looks like this:

```
db.collection("users").doc(props.uid).update({
    points: db.FieldValue.arrayUnion({value: pointObj.value, reason: pointObj.reason})
});
```